# I am not able to copy 14.6 GB file to my NTFS volume

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ntfs, file-transfer

I am trying to copy a virtual machine hdd file (14.6GB size) from external hard drive to my internal hard disk(Label: virtual machines). But After transferring some amount of data it says the destination does not have enough disk space. But it has sufficient amount of disk space.

See this screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Right click on the folder, and click properties. What is the size of the folder you are trying to copy? There should be a _size_, and _size on disk_.

Comment: It is not a folder. It is a file 14.6 GB file and destination is root of drive

Comment: Then check the sizes on the file and not the folder; also, are both drives NTFS and checked for errors?

Answer (score 0):

- You may have a large amount of very small files that may occupy more space than stated
  or
- You may have deleted files that are still on a recycler-like folder and cause the free space to be shown incorrectly
- Disk integrity may be a problem, in which case perform a scandisk, just to make sure the destination drive itself is allright.